# after add row, UITableView add duplicate row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I add a new row in my `UITableView`, it adds a duplicate row. The first row works perfectly, the second row works perfectly, but the third row is a duplicate of the second row.

Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)addExerciseToCustomTable 
{
   // save my parametr from DB
   [self saveExerciseInCacheTableApproach:_approach andRepeat:_repeat andWeight:_weight andTimer:_timer andIndex:_index]; 

   //update position in my TableView from db( 1....10)
   [self updatePositionInCustomViewForAddRow:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([_exerciseForGroupWithSelect count] - 1) ]]; 

   _exerciseForGroupWithSelect = [self loadExerciseFromExerciseCacheWithGroup:groupExerciseId];
   //load new array after update position

  [_customExerciseTable beginUpdates];

  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([_exerciseForGroupWithSelect count] - 1) inSection:0];
  [_customExerciseTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
  [_customExerciseTable endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: When using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`, I don't think it's necessary to call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. Also, make sure you're not calling `reloadData` anywhere before the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this problem - after edit my table i update my DB

now - i load my nutablearray and work with him, after edit complete, save array in DB
it's work perfect